# ConnectionLostException using Spring Boot with Tomcat Websocket

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-websocket

I have a Java Stomp Websocket Client application using Spring Boot 1.3.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT.  Here is my pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My StompSessionHandlerAdapter subscribes to a timer topic which receives a message every second which works fine.  On another topic,  I receive messages every few minutes.  When a message arrives on that topic I receive the following exception in the StompSessionHandlerAdapter handleTransportError method

```
org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.ConnectionLostException: Connection closed
at org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.DefaultStompSession.afterConnectionClosed(DefaultStompSession.java:458)
at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.WebSocketStompClient$WebSocketTcpConnectionHandlerAdapter.afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketStompClient.java:356)
at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.AbstractClientSockJsSession.afterTransportClosed(AbstractClientSockJsSession.java:321)
at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.WebSocketTransport$ClientSockJsWebSocketHandler.afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketTransport.java:172)
at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.onClose(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:143)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.fireEndpointOnClose(WsSession.java:527)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.doClose(WsSession.java:479)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.close(WsSession.java:445)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameClient.close(WsFrameClient.java:94)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameClient.access$100(WsFrameClient.java:31)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameClient$WsFrameClientCompletionHandler.completed(WsFrameClient.java:134)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameClient$WsFrameClientCompletionHandler.completed(WsFrameClient.java:108)
at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:126)
at sun.nio.ch.Invoker$2.run(Invoker.java:218)
at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java:112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here is the code

```
public class SocketSessionHandler extends StompSessionHandlerAdapter {

private StompSession stompSession;


@Override
public void afterConnected(StompSession stompSession, StompHeaders connectedHeaders) {

    this.stompSession = stompSession;

    stompSession.setAutoReceipt(true);
    stompSession.subscribe("/topic/timer", new StompFrameHandler() {

        @Override
        public Type getPayloadType(StompHeaders headers) {
            return String.class;
        }

        @Override
        public void handleFrame(StompHeaders headers, Object payload) {
            System.out.println((payload.toString());
        }
    });
    stompSession.subscribe("/topic/scores", new StompFrameHandler() {

        @Override
        public Type getPayloadType(StompHeaders headers) {
            return ScoresPublish.class;
        }

        @Override
        public void handleFrame(StompHeaders headers, Object payload) {
            ScoresPublish pub = (ScoresPublish)payload;
            System.out.println(pub.getScore());
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void handleException(StompSession session, StompCommand command, StompHeaders headers,
        byte[] payload, Throwable exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
}

@Override
public void handleTransportError(StompSession session, Throwable exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

If I define my own Websocket dependencies in the pom.xml I don't have the problem.  By doing this I also don't get embedded Tomcat started

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.websocket-client-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.tyrus.bundles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tyrus-standalone-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.10</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem. I am getting the same error as well. Heart beat settings doesn't seem to help either.

Comment: I had a deadline to meet so I stuck with the above dependencies.

Answer (score -1):

I think my issue may have been due to my pom.xml missing the spring-messaging dependency.  The following dependencies allow my websocket application to work in Spring Boot Release 1.3.1

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: has the same bug, but dependences does not help =(